# Overload custom comparator to std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, stdmap, custom-compare

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/7/stock-ticker). I came up with this solution:

```
typedef unordered_map<string, double> stockDictType;

class StockTicker {
  class Comparator {
  public:
    inline bool operator() (const string &a, const string &b) const {
      return stocksDict.at(a) < stocksDict.at(b);
    }
  };

  stockDictType stocksDict;

  map<string, stockDictType::iterator, Comparator> stocksTicker; // this is where I need a custom comparator method

  int tickerSize;

public:
  StockTicker(int k): tickerSize(k) {}

  // some other methods
};
```

As is evident, this fails to compile: `StockTicker::stocksDict` is not a static member. Now I can't make it so because I could require multiple instances of the `StockTicker` class.

`std::map` uses a strict comparator function parameter definition (`std::map` will only pass in the keys to be compared), so I can't overload it to pass a reference to the current instance of the `StockTicker` class (which I could've used to get access to `StockTicker::stocksDict` through public getters)

I took inspiration from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28955044/2844164) and the [subsequent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955450/2844164) to do this:

```
typedef unordered_map<string, double> stockDictType;

class StockTicker {
  class Comparator {
  public:
    stockDictType &_stockDictRef;

    explicit Comparator(stockDictType &stocksDict): _stockDictRef(stocksDict) {}

    inline bool operator() (const string &a, const string &b) const {
      return _stockDictRef.at(a) < _stockDictRef.at(b);
    }
  };

  stockDictType stocksDict;
  map<string, stockDictType::iterator, Comparator> stocksTicker(Comparator{stocksDict});
  int tickerSize;

public:
  StockTicker(int k): tickerSize(k) {}

  void addOrUpdate(string name, double price) {
    stocksDict[name] = price;
    stocksTicker.at(name) = stocksDict.find(name);
  }

  vector<stockDictType::iterator> top() {
    vector<stockDictType::iterator> ret(tickerSize);

    auto it = stocksTicker.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < tickerSize; i++, it++)
      ret[i] = it->second;

    return ret;
  }
};
```

This won't compile either. I get this [kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14143967/2844164) in the `StockTicker::addOrUpdate()` and `StockTicker::top()` methods:
`error: '((StockTicker*)this)->StockTicker::stocksTicker' does not have class type`.

I tried a bunch of other stuff too (like declaring a public comparator method in the `StockTicker` class itself and trying to pass a function pointer of it to `std::map`. That failed as well; `StockTicker::stocksTicker` gets declared before the comparator method does and the compiler complains).

Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 std::map<std::string, stockDictType::iterator, Comparator> stocksTicker(Comparator(stocksDict));
```

this defines a member function named `stocksTicker` that takes a `stocksDict` argument of type `Comparator` and returns a `std::map`.

```
std::map<std::string, stockDictType::iterator, Comparator> stocksTicker{Comparator{stocksDict}};
```

This defines a member variable `stocksTicker` which, by default, is initialized with a `Comparator`, which in turn was initialized with the member variable `stocksDict`.

I assume you want the second.

Your syntax was partway between the two.  Whatever compiler you had got confused by this.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57de96df7ad1a32b)

You should `StockTicker(StockTicker &&)=delete` and `StockTicker& operator=(StockTicker &&)=delete`, as maps containing references to their containing class are not safe to move or copy.

Generating an efficient move here is tricky.  I suspect C++17 node splicing might make it possible to do it.  You might have to embed a `std::shared_ptr<stocksDict*>` (yes, a shared pointer to a pointer), and use `.key_comp` to reseat the `stocksDict` in the target.

Comment: This works perfectly. The last two paragraphs make zero sense to me though. Anywhere I can find more explanation on that?

Comment: @Quirk If you have a `struct foo` and within `foo` you store a pointer *back to the struct*, the default move/copy operators will end up with the copied-to `foo` containing a pointer *back to the original foo*.  Like this: `struct foo { foo* self; foo():self(this) {} };  foo f1;  foo f2=f1;` now `f2.self == &f1;` which is **usually** not what you want.  Your comparator in the map effectively has a pointer-to-the-object-containing-the-map (well, to a member field in the object).  2nd last paragraph says easy way to fix this is to ban move/copy.

Comment: Thanks! I was also wondering why this did not work: `std::map<std::string, stockDictType::iterator, Comparator> stocksTicker((Comparator(stocksDict)));` According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28955450/2844164), this should've bypassed the syntax problem, isn't it?

Comment: @quirk `()` are not allowed in inline variable init in a class.  Use `{}`s